# Convert/Parse Float64 into String

Tags: julia

I apologize if this has been answered before, I couldn't find it so far.

So how can Float64 be converted into ASCIIString?

My attempts

```
julia> parse(5.0)
ERROR: `parse` has no method matching parse(::Float64)

julia> convert(ASCIIString, 5.0)
ERROR: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{ASCIIString}, ::Float64)
 in convert at base.jl:13

julia> parsefloat(5.0)
ERROR: `parsefloat` has no method matching parsefloat(::Float64)
```

Julia version 0.3.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [string](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/strings/?highlight=string#string) function:

```
julia> string(0.5)
"0.5"
```

EDIT:

For custom formatted strings, you can use the [@sprintf](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=sprintf#Base.@sprintf) macro:

```
julia> @sprintf("%.2f",0.5)
"0.50"
```